Did Pey Alvar suffer from a mental health illness?
I read somewhere online the Pey Alvar/Azhvar at one point suffered from a mental health condition and yet was loved by Shri Vishnu.
I have not seen this mentioned elsewhere. Is this true? Are there any references to this?
